# Формирование списка ссылок пользователей из массива с учетом времени

Tags: php, массивы, динамические-массивы

Я изучаю PHP и параллельно пишу проект на нем. Все делаю с чистого листа что бы разобраться в языке более детально. Дошел до вывода списка пользователей на странице "все онлайн" ввиде многомерного массива. Смог вывести массив со статусами кто в сети. Массив формируется на лету, нужно на странице сформировать список пользователей в формате **Ник(М-1985)**, при наведении на которых можно перейти по адресу /user/[id]. Дата последнего посещения должна сортировать список по убыванию. Список должен состоять из 10 пользователей, внизу переключение на след. страницу до того момента пока массив не закончится. Циклами я немного по перебирал данный многомерный массив, но сделать такую задачу без руководства никак не могу. Хотел попросить совета где читать с чего начать. Может быть расписать алгоритм функций, в какой последовательности делать. Массив скину для примера, в нем я думаю нет ничего необычного, если кто-то эту задачи посчитает простой и реализует список пользователей виде ссылок на их id, я конечно буду благодарен, но хочется понять.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [nick] => admin
            [gender] => М
            [birth_year] => 1990
            [last_visit] => 2020-02-25 09:06:08
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [nick] => NewNick
            [gender] => Ж
            [birth_year] => 1995
            [last_visit] => 2020-02-23 05:00:53
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [nick] => Апполо
            [gender] => Ж
            [birth_year] => 1981
            [last_visit] => 2020-02-23 05:05:39
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [nick] => СуперНИК
            [gender] => М
            [birth_year] => 1987
            [last_visit] => 2020-02-24 07:52:25
        )

)
```

Comment: Это не вопрос, а какое-то ТЗ. Нужно оставить **один** вопрос.

Comment: Если список пользователей достаётся из базы, то учить SQL - ORDER BY, LIMIT

Comment: Согласен что выглядит как ТЗ, поэтому и решать не нужно. ORDER BY, LIMIT освоить смогу, больше не могу разобраться как вывести из массива список по nick в цикле при этом в виде ссылок

Comment: Неважно. Задавать надо по одному вопросу за раз. Только сначала используя гугл. Начни с того что напиши в адресной строке своего браузера, `php вывести имя в виде ссылки`. И так с каждой задачей по отдельности

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($allUsersOnline))
{
    for ($i =0; $i<count($allUsersOnline); $i++){
        echo "<p>";
        $id = $allUsersOnline[$i]['id'];
        echo "<a href='/user/$id'>" . $allUsersOnline[$i]['nick'] ."(". $allUsersOnline[$i]['gender'] . "-" . $allUsersOnline[$i]['birth_year'] . ")" . "</a>";
        echo "</p>";
    }
}
```

вот вариант для вывода юзеров циклом, может кому-то пригодится. Тут еще не решен вопрос постраничной навигации и сортировки по времени